# Bayes' theorem applied to conditional probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

While doing a probability course, I encountered the following formula in the derivation of a Beta distribution :

$$f(X=x|Y=y) = \frac{P(Y=y|X=x)f(X=x)}{P(Y=y)}$$

Where $f$ denotes the probability density function and $P$ the probability of an event. I did not quite understand why the equation includes the probability $P(Y=y|X=x)$ instead of $f(Y=y|X=x)$ (same for the denominator), as I would expect the formula to be this :
$$f(X=x|Y=y) = \frac{f(Y=y|X=x)f(X=x)}{f(Y=y)}$$
Is this right? If not, what is the intuition behind applying Bayes theorem to conditional probability density functions?

**Update :**

So far, I have found [this resource](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~brian/463-663/week09/Chapter%2003.pdf) (page 4), that supports the second equation. However, [this course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZjlBQbV1KU) from Harvard uses the first equation (at 11:50). Which one is right?

Comment: @NateEldredge That's very strange. I have encountered several resources where the equation they provided was exactly the same as the first one. So they used $P(Y=y|X=x)$ and $P(Y=y)$ (in denominator) but always used probability density for the prior $f(X=x)$

Comment: The equation (after your edit) would make perfect sense if $X$ is continuous and $Y$ is discrete.  Which is exactly the case in the Harvard video.

Comment: In short, the first equation is correct if $X$ is a continuous random variable and $Y$ is a discrete random variable.  The second is correct if $X$ and $Y$ are both continuous random variables.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for clarification. One more question, does $P(Y=y|X=x)$ stand for the probability mass function in the case that $Y$ is a discrete random variable?

Comment: The conditional probability mass function given $X=x$.  Of course, since $P(X=x) = 0$ when $X$ is continuous, this has to be interpreted in the sense of densities.  Namely, for each $y$, it's a function of $x$ such that $P(Y = y \cap a \le X \le b) = \int_a^b P(Y=y \mid X=x) f(X=x)\,dx$.